# get ColumnFilterModes and send server-side in material react table

Tags: reactjs, material-react-table

I want to get the `coulmnfiltermode` in the material react table and do the data filter on the server side.
I could not find any way.

```js
<>
  <MaterialReactTable
    initialState={{
      density: "compact",
      showGlobalFilter: true,
      showColumnFilters: true,
    }}
    lt
    columns={columns}
    data={data?.queryResult ?? []}
    manualFiltering
    manualPagination
    manualSorting
    onColumnFiltersChange={setColumnFilters}
    onGlobalFilterChange={setGlobalFilter}
    rowCount={data?.totalCount ?? 0}
    state={{
      columnFilters,
      globalFilter,
      isLoading,
      pagination,
      showAlertBanner: isError,
      showProgressBars: isFetching,
      sorting,
    }}
  />
</>
```

I used `filterFns` and `onColumnFilterFnsChange` but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

The state you are looking for is `columnFilterFns`. Manage that state just like how the `columnFilters` state is managed and you can read that state to see which mode is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with that until I found an example code from Mantine React Table ( fork of Material React Table ) that uses columFilterFns state :

[react-query-example](https://github.com/KevinVandy/mantine-react-table/blob/84a8935a57571957539437db448039b6afc54b48/apps/mantine-react-table-docs/examples/react-query/sandbox/src/TS.tsx#L151)

Most relevant parts that you can find there:

```
const [columnFilterFns, setColumnFilterFns] = //filter modes
useState<MRT_ColumnFilterFnsState>(
  Object.fromEntries(
    columns.map(({ accessorKey }) => [accessorKey, 'contains']),
  ),
); 

...
const table = useMantineReactTable({
  ...
  enableColumnFilterModes: true,
  onColumnFilterFnsChange: setColumnFilterFns,
  state: { columnFilterFns }
...
```

Notice that the initial filter functions names for all ColumnsFns are 'contains' in this example.

Then you can use useEffect() to 'listen' to changes.